# Is wrapping a method a kind of design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, adapter, decorator, wrapper, facade

Can anyone tell me if this code is a design pattern or not?

Imagine your codebase has hundreds of calls to a method `GetJsonAsync`. For example:

```
var request = new HttpRequest(url);

return request.GetJsonAsync<T>();
```

You want to add a header to every request, so you create a wrapper method like:

```
public static Task<T> GetJsonWithHeader<T>(this HttpRequest request)
{
    var requestWithHeader = AddHeaders(request);

    return requestWithHeader.GetJsonAsync<T>();
}
```

Which means those first two lines of code can be changed to:

```
var request = new HttpRequest(url);

return request.GetJsonWithRequestId<T>();
```

I called this class a "Wrapper". But is it actually an example of the Decorator pattern? Or some other design pattern?

Comment: You are decorating the request(Decorator) or Building the request (Builder) ? But any code re use pattern can fall into DRY principle in common.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the object types rather than `var`. Is `requestWithHeader` a subclass of `request`? Why does the third code fragment call a different Json method from the first two? Who calls the `static` method in the second fragment?